# php check 2 records using multiple num_rows?

Tags: php

I've created a prepared statment code that show me if the EMAIL exists.

This code bellow show me if email exists...

```
    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT email, name FROM public_users WHERE email = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($email, $name );
    $stmt->store_result();
    $row = $stmt->fetch();

    if($stmt->num_rows == 1) {

         header("Location: ../member?error=2");
         exit();            

    } else {


    }
```

This code is correct and working but... how can i use the same code to check if NAME exists? Because i already used ->num_rows...

Comment: Something like `WHERE email = ? OR name = ?`?

Comment: You can't use the sql statement as is but you can add ".. AND name IS NOT NULL" to the statement

Comment: @Tom I think this is part of a new user registration system, he's trying to check if the email or username is already in use.

Comment: @Barmar ... maybe they need to be more specific as to what this is going to be used for.

Comment: He's using the same language in the question at the end as he used in describing what the code already does. The query currently checks if the email exists, he wants to check if the name exists. I assumed he's using "If XXX exists" in the same way in both places.

Answer (score 0):

Add another check to the query.

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT email, name FROM public_users WHERE email = ? OR name = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $email, $name);
```

Comment: Why do you assume that he has the value of name?

Comment: Because he wants to check if the name already exists, similar to the way he checked if the email already exists.